# dygraphs: select point on closest curve w.r.t. only the y-dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, dygraphs

I require dygraphs to always 'lock on' to the nearest x-axis point given the mouse position, even when 'highlightSeries' is enabled, but no series is 'selected'.

Currently, when 'highlightSeries' is enabled dygraphs will select the closest point in Euclidean space by Euclidean distance, but this is usually not the correct functionality for my use-case. Instead, I require it to select the closest point where one of the dimensions is fixed (i.e. x-axis), so it can only rely on the y-axis when determining which is the closest point. I require this to function with any number of plotted curves.

Note that similar functionality is exemplified when the user 'selects' a curve by clicking on it, as demonstrated in the 'Highlight Closest Series' example (http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-series). Similarly, correct functionality is offered when the dygraph plots curves without any 'highlightSeries' enabled.

However, I require this type of functionality even when there are multiple curves, 'highlightSeries' is enabled, and the user has not selected one in particular. In this case, it should select the nearest curve based on a fixed x-axis, but whichever is nearest on the y-axis.

[image: Closest point selection in dygraph]

Please note that the intersection of the cross-hair is also where the mouse was located when the screenshot was taken (the mouse itself is not displayed). Dygraph has selected the closest point in Euclidean space, which is highlighted on the curve itself.

To reiterate, instead of this behavior, dygraphs should select the point on the curve at the x-axis point where the mouse is located. In this case, it would be where the gray vertical cross-hair component cuts the orange time-series curve.

How should I achieve this type of behavior?

*** EDIT ***

One (bad) work-around I have created is as follow:

```
$("#dyGraphs").mousemove(function (e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   g.setSelection(g.findClosestRow(relX));
});
```

Unfortunately, due to the nature of 'mousemove' this interferes with the click-and-drag (for zooming) highlight interaction native to dygraphs, and also requires more logic to stop the circles on the curve from rounding up too soon and jumping to the next data-point. Surely there has to be a better solution?

*** EDIT 2 ***

Below is a workaround that selects (locks-on to) the nearest curve/series given a fixed row (x-axis point), by working out which series is closest to the current Y position (minus a 10px offset, unique to my situation). Also, it will not interfere with the click-and-drag (for zooming) highlight interaction native to dygraphs and it provides basic logic to stop the circles on the curve from rounding up too soon and jumping to the next data-point (n.b. using fixed value or 90px offset unique to my use case).

```
$("#dyGraphs").mousemove(function (e){
var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
var relX2 = relX - ( $("#dyGraphs").width() - 90 ) / g.numRows() / 2
var yOffsets = [];
var closestDistance = 999 // Arbitrary large number
var closestIdx = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < g.numColumns() - 2; i++) {
    yOffsets.push( g.toDomYCoord(g.getValue(g.findClosestRow(relX2), i+1)) )
}

$.each(yOffsets, function (i,e) {
    var difference = Math.abs(e - parseFloat(relY-10));
    if (difference  < closestDistance) {
        closestDistance = difference;
        closestIdx = i;
    }
})

if (e.which != 1 && closestIdx !== -1 ) {
    g.setSelection(g.findClosestRow(relX2), g.getLabels()[closestIdx+1]);
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: "Selection mode" is currently conflated with `highlightSeriesOpts`, as you've discovered. Feel free to chime in on this issue if you'd like this to be an option: https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/371